# DataTables export PDF, Export original data from database not edited

Tags: datatables

I have one column in my table called "Info" where i have a code to render that column where if string is longer then 20 characters it will shorten it and put '...' at the end of string. Here is an example:

```
{
    targets: 4,
    "data": "info",
    "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
        if(type === 'export') {
            return data;
        }
        if (data != null) {
            return type === 'display' && data.length > 20 ?
                '<p data-toggle="tooltip" title="' + data + '">' + data.substr(0, 20) + '...</p>' : data;
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    }
 },
```

Problem here is when I generate PDF I have data in that column shorten with '...', is it possible to have full data (full string) in pdf, excel etc. while having it shorten in table (column). I can always make one more column and make it invisible and then put that column in pdf. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `render` function, your correctly looking to see if the `type` is `export`:

```
if(type === 'export') {
    return data;
}
```

However, the type isn't `export` by default, even for PDFs or excels. You need to add the variable `orthogonal` to the export button decalaration object. This is then passed on to the `render` function as `type`

```
buttons: [
  {
    extend: 'excel',
    exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
  },
  {
    extend: 'pdf',
    exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
  }
]
```

More info on orthogonal here:
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/outputFormat-orthogonal.html